# Does Autodesk Forge Reality Capture API support panorama photos to reconstruct point cloud

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-realitycapture

I am looking for this question and could not find it after google it.
My purpose is to use panorama photos to create point clouds.
Just wondering does this API support that? or it is designed for drone photos especially?

Answer (score 1):

Forge Reality Capture is to create 3D textured meshes from Photos, not point clouds per say. It is really made to create meshes from objects. You can for example take photos of a building or your keyboard. But it will not work from photos taken inside a room.